# Latitude and longitude

Tags: gps, position, coordinates, latitude-longitude

Actually I have the decimal values of latitude and longitude.

In a 2d referential, are those values the x an y coordenates?

> example :
>
> in a position P
>
> latitude = 41.15  longitude = -8.64
>
> So, in a 2d dimension P is defined by (41.15,-8.64) ?

Thanks

Comment: They wouldn't be called 'x, y' coordinates as such since that often (somewhat casually) refers to Cartesian coordinates, whereas lat and long are on the surface of a sphere. But you could certainly write lat/long using a `(lat, long)` notation if you like. You just don't want to confuse them with a Cartesian system.

Comment: Yes, and you are gonna be here (http://maps.google.fr/maps/myplaces?ll=41.15,-8.64&spn=0.011294,0.026157&ctz=-60&t=m&z=16)

Comment: ther's a way to convert from my notation to cartesian coordinates?;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, its exactly opposite:

The coordinate (lat, lon) corresponds to the pair (y,x)

So when passinge lat, lon to mathematical routines, like point in polygon calculations
pass in order (lon, lat).

longitude raises parallell to the aequator, which corresponds to our x achsis direction we normally use in cartesian (x,y) systems.

Unfortunatley for historical reasons, the latitude is often written before longitude. (The cause might be that the latitude was easier to determine than the longitude.)

This all leads for us SW developpers to the bad situation, that sometimes functions use (lat,lon) order, sometimes when working with transformations from (lon,lat) to (x,y) or mathematical routines, the order lon, lat must be used. Be careful, every person I know someday has accidentally exchanged that.

In your example:
P is related to (-8.64), 41.15).
But lat,lon are spherical coordinates, for most application you must convert them to cartesian (x,y) .
But this is another question.

Comment: how do I convert them to cartesian?

Is that correct:
x = radius_of_world * Math.cos(longitude) * Math.cos(latitude)
y = radius_of_world * Math.sin(longitude) * Math.cos(latitude)

Comment: I dont know you formula, there are many: this works for an area up to 100 km: the y is easy: just meters_per_degrees * latitude; x = meters_per_degrees * longitude / cos(toRadians(center_latitude)); meters_per_degrees = earth_circum_fence / 360.0; (111 km); this works for distances up to 100km. Choose any center_latitude you want (usually in the center of interest), but dont change it later!. All points must use the same transformation center (latitude); Pleas econsider upvoting the answre, too!

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with units. In systems like Google Maps, those numbers are usually in degrees. **Usually**.

They might also be in radians, though, so at least make sure of what unit the API is using.

Comment: I'm using those Google numbers, I think they are the convertion from polar notation to decimal values.. My question is, is there a way to convert from those values to cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Then the integer part of those numbers is in degrees... The decimal parts are [minutes and seconds of arc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minute_of_arc) converted to decimal, yes. You'll have to do some simple division. One degree equals 60 minutes, and one minute equals 60 seconds. As for conversion, [good luck and happy coding](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28446/computational-most-efficient-way-to-convert-cartesian-to-geodetic-coordinates).